# How can I highlight a section of an article in the backend using django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, highlight

This is how I create my article

`class CreateArticleView(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
        Class handles creating of articles
    """

```
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
renderer_classes = (ArticleJSONRenderer,)
queryset = Article.objects.all()

def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    article = request.data.get('article', {})

    if self.request.user.is_verified is False:
        message = error_messages['email_verification']
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

    context = {"request": request}
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=article, context=context)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save(author=request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)`
```

`

This is how I get to view a single article, therefore I would like to fetch a single article and be able to highlight several parts of the article and manage to comment on them

```
class GetUpdateDeleteArticle(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
renderer_classes = (ArticleJSONRenderer,)
queryset = Article.objects.all()
serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
lookup_field = 'slug'

@staticmethod
def validate_author(request, article):
    if request.user.pk != article.author_id:
        message = error_messages['unauthorised']
        return Response(message, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    :param request: user requests to get an article
    :param kwargs: slug field is passed in the url
    :return: data and response if article exists
    """

    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])
    except Article.DoesNotExist:
        message = error_messages['article_404']
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    serializer = ArticleSerializer(
        instance=article, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a design decision in the model level and less of an API issue. I would go with the following DB design:

A model Highlight that stores a reference to the article, the begining index of the highlighted part of the text and the ending index. So, something roughly like this:

```
class Highlight(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='highlights')
    start = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    end = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Then a Comment model. A common design is to use [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) so that comments can be used with any model in your application. Something like this should suffice:

```
class Comment(TimeStampedModel):
    text = models.TextField(blank=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

You can now build an API around this design where clients create highlights by sending the article id, start and end indices of the highlighted text. Comments can also be created using the highlight's id. Retrieving the highlights for an article should also be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the idea it helped.

Comment: @sylvia you're welcome. Also, if you're ok with it, then don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: If I were to have a link of maybe an image inside the body of the article would there be a way of skipping it when highlighting it

Comment: @sylvia that's now a bit complex. You can use some libraries like beautiful soup or others to separate all the extra entities from the main text depending on markup language you're using. But that will be complex to implement